# How to handle Flutter widget rebuilding with BLOC?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, bloc, flutter-bloc

In regards to Flutter's way to rebuild widgets when navigating between routes, there is this issue: [Pages on Navigator stack rebuild when a new page is pushed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655) where the dev team and others provided these interesting insights:

1. [About this reported behavior in the issue itself](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655#issuecomment-348287396):

> This is working as intended. In general, you should assume that all widgets can rebuild at any time, that they don't is mostly just an optimization. [...]

2. [Further (re)explained here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655#issuecomment-412413030):

> You should generally assume that every widget will be rebuilt every frame, and design your build methods to be idempotent [...]

3. [When asked how to handle fetching data in `build(context)`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655#issuecomment-423902769):

> you'll need to restructure your code so that the data is not fetched again [...].

---

I am using BLoC to fetch remote data. For example, in my `HomePage`:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
      bloc: sl.get()..add(const GetHomeEvent()), // `sl` from package `GetIt`, a dependency injector
      builder: (context, state) {
        return AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: state.join(
            (initial) => const EmptyHome(),
            (loading) => const LoadingHome(),
            (success) => LoadedHome(homeEntity: success.homeEntity),
            (failure) => FailedHome(errorMessage: failure.message),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

As you can read, I build a `BlocBuilder` and upon its instantiation, I asked the `HomeBloc` to fetch data:

```
HomeBloc() : super(HomeState.initial()) {
  on<GetHomeEvent>((event, emit) async {
     print('load home event request');
     // code to load home and notify of result via `emit()`
    );
  });
```

The log `load home event request` gets printed multiple times as I navigate in and out from my home page.

**How should I go about and prevent unnecessarily reloading the home ?**

- Should I simply cache it via a local variable?
- How to handle refresh properly (e.g. hit F5 in the web browser)?

Answer (score 0):

build method is such a method which will be executed frequently. For screen pages who need to fetch some data, it is prefereed to create stateful widget instead of stateless. And then you should add event on bloc inside initState method instead of build. Don’t forget to delete ..({event}) in build methos. In that way you will get rid off problem with unnecessary API requests.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. After posting my question I did some investigation and I also thought `StatefulWidget` could be the solution. However, I noticed that my `_HomeScreenState` of my now `StatefulWidget HomeScreen` was also init multiple times. So adding `GetHomeEvent` in `initState` will cause multiple API calls... And finally, what do you mean by "Don’t forget to delete ..({event}) in build methos"?

Comment: I think key of your issue is here in last sentence. You need to remove event adding code in build method. If you add event on same bloc instance in initState and instead of 
`return BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(bloc: sl.get()..add(const GetHomeEvent()),` 
you need to write 
`return BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(bloc: sl.get(),`

Comment: Okay, thanks now I understand better. So if I remove `..add(const GetHomeEvent()` which does indeed calls the API upon building my `HomeScreen`, where and when should I actually send the `const GetHomeEvent()` to my `HomeBloc`?

Comment: I said about it. Inside initState method, which exists inside stateful widget’s state class. Because even if parent widget’s build method is executed, child widget’s initState will not be executed. It means about our case, if you do navigator.pop this page then again push the page, for this case initState will be executed again. In short it will called only once, when you need, no duplicates. If you find the answer useful, then please accept it